# MATLAB: Function that computes the coefficients of the polynomial that is formed by multiplying 2 other polynomials

Tags: function, matlab, multiplication

I need to come up with a MATLAB function that computes the coefficients of the polynomial that is formed by multiplying 2 other polynomials.

I know that I need to somehow use conv(a,b) or something like that but I need to CREATE a function somehow. Help please!

Answer (score 3):

Is this homework?  Anyway, you do want to use `conv`, and it basically solves your problem.  What was the problem beyond that?

Comment: i know about conv, but I have to create a custom function that gives the same result as conv.

Comment: So what do you need help with?

Comment: creating a function that looks like this: 
CombinedPolyCoeff = polyMultiply ( polyCoeffA, polyCoeffB)

Comment: @Frank: Are you allowed to use `conv`?  Otherwise, do you know (in terms of loops) what `conv` does internally?

Comment: in terms of loops I have no idea...if u could explain i would really appreciate it

Comment: Let's look at two degree-two polynomials, `a*x^2 + b*x + c` and `d*x^2 + e*x + f`.  What is their product (compute it by hand)?  Where does the coefficient for `x^k` in the product come from for each `k`?

Comment: adx^4 + bdx^3 + cdx^2 + aex^3 + bex^2 + cex + afx^2 + bfx + cf... x^k comes from multiplying the x terms together

Comment: Could you write a loop that does the multiplication like you did by hand?

Comment: nah i dont think so... i'm pretty new with this program

Comment: Let's say you have `a*x^k` and `b*x^l`; what is their product?  How do you multiply sums of things (in general)?

Comment: ab(x^k)(x^1)....multiplying each term of one quantity with each term of the other quantity and then adding them all together at the end....i understand the mathematics, but i dont understand how to construct a code that will give me the desired effect.

Comment: How are you representing your polynomials?  Given a vector, what polynomial does it represent?

Comment: polyCoeffA= (a,b,c) polyCoeffB= (d,e,f)

Comment: But what do those mean in terms of powers of `x`?

Comment: ax^2+bx+c       dx^2+ex+f (sorry to sound frustrated but i dont know where this is going, and i'm kinda in a time crunch so please try and get to the point faster)

Comment: You want to walk down the terms of the polynomials using a doubly nested loop (one to walk over `polyCoeffA` and one to walk over `polyCoeffB`), multiply the coefficients, and add that product to the correct element of the result vector.

Comment: lol that makes very little sense to me...any way you can put it in matlab function form or something that I could grasp

Comment: Since it's homework, I don't want to just give you the answer.  Can you write pseudocode for how to do the multiplication?  Can you write out in English what the algorithm is?

Comment: i understand...uh honestly i have no idea how to start the function/code except from what the form of the function should be.

Comment: Do you know the algorithm to multiply polynomials by hand?  It looks like you do.  Can you write that (in English) in terms of loops?

Comment: no i don't know how to write it in terms of loops....should i use a "for loop" or something of that sort?

Comment: Yes.  You want an outer loop that goes through the coefficients of one polynomial, and an inner loop that goes through the coefficients of the other one.

Comment: (so something like) 
for a:f
end
for c:d
end
(i am completely guessing at this point)

Comment: More like `for k = [1:length(polyCoeffA)]; for l = [1:length(polyCoeffB)]; ...; end; end` with the `...` part filled in.

Comment: so you create 2 matrices and then for the ... part would u put k times l?

Comment: You would get `polyCoeffA(k)` and `polyCoeffB(l)`, which are the coefficients of `x^(k-1)` and `y^(l-1)` respectively, multiply them, and add them into the result vector.

Comment: so i would get for k=blah; for l=blah polyCoeffA(k)*polyCoeffB(l); end; end

Comment: @Frank: it sounds like you need some help learning MATLAB. not sure what to tell you other than look at the MATLAB tutorial and ask *specific* questions here.